# Localization in iOS 11 , swift 4

Tags: localization, translation, ios11, swift4

I've got a problem after I upgrading to iOS 11 and Xcode version changes to 9. 
When I choose the "Burmese" language, "Setting" menu text does not translate but the rest menu texts are translated into Burmese language.

```
var TableArray = [["Home","Buy", "Watch Later"],["Notification","Settings","User Guide"]]
```

Menu texts put in array and that locates in table view cell.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.imageView?.image = menuIconImage[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString(TableArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], comment: "")
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Tharlon", size: 17)
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.blue
    tableView.rowHeight = 56.0;

    return cell

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    prefs.setValue(false, forKey: "FLAG")
    prefs.setValue(true, forKey: "DRAWER")
    debugPrint("Click LogIn")

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TableArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.imageView?.image = menuIconImage[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Tharlon", size: 17)

    cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString(TableArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], comment: "")
}
```

However I tried , all the **texts are changed to "Burmese" except "Settings"** text. So, I add following codes again inside table function but it **does not work.**

```
if (cell.textLabel?.text == "Settings") {
        cell.textLabel?.text = NSLocalizedString(TableArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row], comment: "")
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Tharlon", size: 17)
    }
```

Can anyone help me please? I'm still finding solution for this since last 2 days. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
if Language.currentLanguage() == "ar"
{
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .right
}
else
{
     cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = .left
}
```

this worked with me